# Do you lose contributions of a project if you get removed from this project?

Tags: github, git-commit

I can't seemed to find this information anywhere, but just wanna ask that if you are a contributor of a project and you worked on it so you can see all of those contributions on the chart, but then for whatever reason the owner of the project removed you, do you lose all of those contributions? as in will those green contribution grids(the days you work on it) go back to grey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the contributions are based on the commit email ID, and do not have anything to do with the corresponding GitHub account having access to the repository. GitHub attributes a commit to a particular account if the email ID used with the commit is registered under that account.

So, unless the email IDs of past commits are in some way changed later, the contributions will still be visible, as long as the repository is public.

This also works the other way around. Anyone can set any email ID in their git configuration while committing, so it is trivial to falsely attribute commits to someone else, when viewing the contribution chart in GitHub.

Comment: **the contributions will still be visible, as long as the repository is public** So if the repo is private and if you get removed, then those contributions will go away?

Comment: @kjunz The contributions will still be visible in the repository chart (which you can no longer see if you don't have access), but not in your profile (again since you no longer have access). Any contribution will always be attributed to your account as long as the commit email ID is one of the emails registered under your account.